# Is there a free version of Visual Studio that comes with an HTML WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: gratis, html-editor, wysiwyg, visual-studio

I tried Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, and there is no HTML designer view that I get in the professional version.

Is that a configuration issue, or the feature is simply not available?

Is there any other 'free' version of Visual Studio that allows to edit HTML files with a preview/designer mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition supports Design view for HTML, but to enable this -in a website project - need to right click a file, and in "open with" options - select 'HTML (web forms ) Editor' - got this from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpoY1_YKGHQ . This works the same way in PRO and in Community versions.